# Should an unused argument be null-checked?

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, null

Given a generic interface like this *(it's not my actual case, but serves as a minimum example)*:

```
/** Generic interface for unary functions on strings. */
public interface StringTransformer {
  /**
   * Transform the given non-null string.
   * @param x string to be transformed
   * @return transformed string
   * @throws NullPointerException if x is null
   */
   String apply(String x);
}
```

Suppose I have an implementation returning a constant value regardless of the passed argument:

```
public class EmptyAllStrings implements StringTransformer {
  public String apply(String x) {
    return "";
  }
}
```

My doubt is whether it is a good idea to add a check to throw a NPE if the argument is `null`, even if it would not matter in this case.

```
  public String apply(String x) {
    Objects.checkNotNull(x);
    return "";
  }
```

Points against checking:

- `null` can be used in situations where the specific class used is known
- less code

Points supporting checking:

- effectively compliant with interface javadoc
- may help to spot `null`-related bugs even when a `null`-resilient class is used

Is there any more or less "authoritative" guideline suggesting one of the two options in cases like this?

Comment: an unused argument should be removed

Comment: @Stultuske not if you want to implement an interface.

Comment: @daniu then that interface should have the method without the argument. it's a bit like putting setSpeed(int speed); in an interface, and in the implementation setSpeed(int speed) { /* what to do here? */ }.
Sure, it works, but is it good design?

Comment: We're not talking about setSpeed(int speed), we're talking about `String apply(String x)` where you clearly cannot remove the argument, just because there exists one, not very useful, implementation that doesn't use the argument.

Comment: @Stultuske You are arguing that `Consumer<String>` should include a method `accept()`?

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt so, we're talking about a method that is supposed to apply the value passed as parameter. since that is not what they want ... is that good design?

Comment: @daniu don't really get your point there, might just because I don't use Consumer all that much. but at this point, the user could assume the method to have been "applied" on the parameter passed, which might be misleading. Overall, imo, it's never recommended to pass null as parameter. or, to pass parameters that aren't used

Comment: @Stultuske My point is that it's very common for the implementor of an interface to ignore one or more arguments of that interface's method, and that that doesn't mean the interface is badly designed.

Comment: @daniu the way I understand it, is that both the interface and implementation are from the OP. if not, maybe the question is: why isn't the variable used? maybe the user doesn't understand the design of the interface.

Comment: @Stultuske the interface states that implementors "transform the given non-null string". The implementation does that. Another implementation may return the contents of the file with the given name; that implementation would be meaningless without an argument. So both interface and implementation are fine from what we know.

Comment: @daniu to copy-paste the interfaces documentation: param x string to be transformed * return transformed string -> so it is the transformation of the parameter that should be returned. how can it than be that the param is not used?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would want to check for `null` here. The idea is that a `NullPointerException` is thrown by the JVM, not Java code... if anything, I'd expect to throw an `IllegalArgumentException` for this kind of checks (although I've worked with people who were of a different opinion, so YMMV).

Here though, you effectively return something from nothing; you have no idea whether the surrounding code may need a `null` check. It's just not this code's responsibility.

And the Javadoc comment means "might throw an exception", not "is guaranteed to" IMO.

Comment: I used to think IllegalArgumentException was more appropriate.  But between the [NullPointerException documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html), which says “Applications should throw instances of this class to indicate other illegal uses of the null object,” the fact that [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) throws it, and the fact that all Java APIs throw it when null is passed as an (unacceptable) argument, I am convinced it’s the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually seen this done a few times and I always have the question "Why?", basically it's bad development, as others have said it's not the code that should throw an NPE that is where the JVM kicks in, an NPE is developer error. Having an implemented method that always returns the same thing is pointless and not needed so should be removed otherwise provide a correct implementation and have a null check (if there is a chance that the argument could be null) throwing an IllegalArgumentEx with a message and handle that correctly elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the root of the problem is the existence of a `@throws NullPointerException` in the documentation of an *interface*. `NullPointerException` should be used for programming errors, but here you are just stating a contract, not an implementation. Let the implementing classes decide how to handle null values, and adjust the documentation accordingly.

In case the interface code is given and unchangeable, then in my opinion you can either:

- check for `null` even though you don't use the argument (preferable) or;
- override the documentation in the subclass, stating that your implementation won't use the argument in any way, not even for the check.